# ios: How can convert integer number to array of characters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I'm trying to convert integer number into array of integers.

For example I have this number 123456. I need to have

```
ArrayOfNumbers [0] = 6
ArrayOfNumbers [1] = 5
ArrayOfNumbers [2] = 4
ArrayOfNumbers [3] = 3
ArrayOfNumbers [4] = 2
ArrayOfNumbers [5] = 1
```

any of you knows how can I do this? I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but enough to be going on with.

Comment: This is not a duplicate @Jissay

Comment: Not exactly, for sure, but there is enough matter to go on i think :)

Comment: This definitely is a duplicate, though I can't point at an example.  The question comes up about once a week, with minor variations.  (Though more often in Java than Objective-C -- one would hope that anyone using Objective-C wouldn't need to ask such a basic question.)

Comment: (And it's appalling how many bad answers have been provided.  Anyone ever seen the `%` operator before??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK (sigh!)

```
int array[6];
int i = 0;
int number = 123456;
while (i < 6) {
   array[i] = number % 10;
   number = number / 10;
   i++;
}
```

(Behavior for negative numbers is undefined.)

Comment: `array[i++]` saves a line and trolls your co-workers.

Comment: @Abizern - I studiously avoid the user of non-isolated `++` operators, since it makes my head hurt.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a method like like this for it:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) numberToArray : (NSNumber *) nmb
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nmb];
    NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[str length]];
    for (int i=0; i < [str length]; i++)
    {
        NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:i]];
        [characters addObject:ichar];
    }

    return characters;
}
```